# Show Windows folder as a toolbar in Chrome

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

After bookmark syncing in Chrome burned me yet again, I've decided to store my bookmarks in Dropbox so I can share on multiple machines. I would like to be able to show a toolbar in chrome that points to my bookmarks folder in Windows. I'm would love it if I do something like the Bookmarks Bar but pointed to a folder on Windows. I'd even be willing to install an extension to do this. I can't seem to figure out how to make this happen though.

Comment: Chrome does not have a bookmarks folder. Seems like an XY problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let assume as an example that you want to bookmark the Download folder.

1. On the address bar, type: `file:///C:/Users/Yourusername/Downloads/` (or `C:/Users/Yourusername/Downloads/` as indicated by @fred_dot_u on the comments)
2. The folder will be displayed. Bookmark it, select the folder `Favorite Bar`. Give your bookmark a name. Click Done.

[image]

3. Clicking the bookmark will open and show the folder's contents inside Chrome.

Comment: even the bare path c:/user/username/downloads will work.

Comment: This is very close to what I want. However, since the folder I adding is a collection of *.url files (saved bookmarks) when I click on them in Chrome it actually shows the content of the file instead of navigating to the site:
`[InternetShortcut]`
`URL=https://portal.azure.com/#home`

Comment: @MikeCole Use this extension [.URL handler](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/url-handler/nhmccpjmdhejpfhafcfajkgifkmjhkgf). When the .url file is opened, the extension will redirect the url to the correct website. Don't forget to allow the permission "Allow access to file URLs". If you don't allow, the extension wont work.